# Django include template using Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, python-3.x, django-templates

I came from a Rails background thus the question may seem stupid. 
In Rails, when we create a Ajax request, then we can update a view by rendering a partial using the javascript selector like the following:

```
$("#dashboardEmails").html("<%=j render partial: 'emails', locals: {emails: @emails} %>");
```

How can I do that in Django template? I've tried the following:

```
$.ajax({
        type: frm.attr('method'),
        url: frm.attr('action'),
        data: frm.serialize() + "&submit=connect",
        success: function (data) {
          if(data['tables'].length > 0){
            $('#data-connection-info').html("{% include 'projects/connection_info.html' with data='"data"' %}");
          }
          console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
          console.log("Error");
        }
});
```

Here, I want to update the view with a template `projects/connection_info.html`, also passing a javascript variable (**data**) to the template using `with`. But it is not working.

Any idea how can I achieve that?

**UPDATE**

I passed the template from the view like:

```
template = render_to_string('projects/connection_info.html', json_data)
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(template), content_type='application/json')
```

Then in the ajax success function updates the DOM:

```
success: function (data) {
          $('#data-connection-info').html(data);
 }
```

In this way the problem is solved. :)

Comment: you can't do it this way, but you can return from your django view full rendered html or empty string and always set the result inside the DOM.

Comment: @BearBrown Any example regarding your solution?

Comment: save the html of the template in a variable. `var connection_info_html ={% include 'projects/connection_info.html' %}` After ajax success change use that variable to update DOM . Django's include, extends etc are processed on the server so once the html is rendered you can't use it.

Comment: One thing you can do is use render_to_string and return a JsonResponse in the view. Then you can just insert the result into the page using javascript via a method like .html

Comment: @DisneylandSC I passed the template with `render_to_string` and `HttpResponse`. Now the `.html` updates the dom element, but the data passed with the template are not accessible into the passed template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I passed the template from the view like:

```
template = render_to_string('projects/connection_info.html', json_data)
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(template), content_type='application/json')
```

Then in the ajax success function updates the DOM:

```
success: function (data) {
          $('#data-connection-info').html(data);
 }
```

In this way the problem is solved. :)

Comment: Why `json.dumps()` the rendered template ??? A plain html response works as well.